# Fixing the newly created "geometric-invariant-theor" tag

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, tag-management, character-limit

A tag for *geometric invariant theory* has been created today, but it comes with a problem: the final "y" is missing, therefore its current name is [geometric-invariant-theor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-invariant-theor).

Is there an upper limit for the length of a tag, beyond which tags get automatically truncated? If not, could a moderator add the missing letter (rather than create a correctly spelled tag, retag all the currently tag questions, and then delete the misspelled tag)?

Comment: As far as the truncation of the tag name is concerned, this is at present status-by-design, and according to SE response to a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange ([Raising the 25 chars limit for tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197889/214632)) this probably won't be changing soon.

Comment: BTW the edit in which this tag was (likely) created - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/717626) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1774158/revisions) - had the following edit summary: "new tag geometric-invariant-theor like mathoverflow".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an upper limit for the length of a tag, beyond which tags get automatically truncated?

Yes. It is <s>25</s> [35](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490).

> If not, could a moderator add the missing letter (rather than create a correctly spelled tag, retag all the currently tag questions, and then delete the misspelled tag)?

While due to the character limit, moderators cannot rename to the tag you proposed, it is the case that  moderators can rename tags (technically it is not a rename but a merge into another tag with a different name, but functionally its about the same, in a way under-the-hood it is what you do not want, but there will be no manual retags and bumps). Thus, if you have another name to propose, you could still fix the problem.